# Why non-canonical URL with a fragment identifier (#) is shared with a `_escaped_fragment_` query parameter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, canonical-link

I'm using [Facebook's Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) to share a URL like...

http://www.example.com/products/9-some-name#!23

In the HTML for that page, a different URL (also with a fragment identifier) is specified as the canonical URL, like

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/products/9-canonical-name#!23">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/products/9-canonical-name#!23">
```

In my Facebook profile, the shared URL shows as

http://www.example.com/products/9-canonical-name?_escaped_fragment_=23

Is that a bug?
(I expected the shared URL to be posted as-is, i.e. not the canonical one, and without any transformation.)

**UPDATE**

After more investigation I realized this doesn't have anything to do with fragment identifiers. The essential problem is that the URL posted by Facebook in the user's profile is the URL in `og:url`, not the originally shared URL. And it seems that can't be changed (as I understand from [a related question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69784/how-do-you-share-a-non-canonical-url-on-facebook)).

Comment: The hash part of an URL only has meaning on the client. Facebook suspects that you might show different content for different hashes – and so they request the escaped fragment format that Google invented for such cases, to make sure that the server can deliver the right piece of content.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for sharing best practices on Facebook the the og:url should be a URL with no session id or extraneous parameters. All shares on Facebook will use the og:url as the identifying URL.

[developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags)